# Azure VNet with app services and app gateway

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway, vnet

I created an azure vnet with 2 subnets, then I created two app services inside one of the subnet.
I thought the web app won't be accessible from the internet, but I can navigate to the app via it's url and the page loads.

I want to make the two website (app services) private and I'd like to use App Gateway to be the only public entry point.
Could you advice how can I do that and if that's a good idea, please?

Answer (score 2):

Created Application gateway added two App service in backend pool:

[image]

Set up routing rules to define how incoming requests should be directed to the backend pool, Add listener and backend targets like below:

[image]

In backend setting:

[image]

In backend target add your path-based routing click on `Add Multiple targets to create a path-based rule` and configure like below:

[image]

Once deployed, In virtual machine add ***Service endpoint*** `Microsoft.web` to subnet like below:

[image]

In Application gateway -> healthy probes add HTTP protocol, host and appropriate path and add your backend setting like below:

[image]

Now, you can your backend are in healthy state

[image]

In backend setting make sure to select ***override with host name*** as **`yes`** and ***pick hostname from backend target*** verify the ***custom probe*** like below:

[image]

In app service -> under Networking -> Access restriction you can restrict app service it shows as 403 error, and you can use App Gateway to be the only public entry point.

[image]
.
[image]

when I hit the public Ip address in Application gateway App service are redirected successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

***Reference***:

[Azure Application Gateway architecture with multiple App Services](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-application-gateway-architecture-multiple-app-services-%C4%87osi%C4%87/)  by *Ratko cosic*

Comment: That's sounds good. So now the access is private as I wanted. How can I deploy the app now? I'd like to use devops pipeline, is there any build-in way to be able to implement CI/CD to this private web service?